# Leer el atributo "version" del comienzo de un xml con php

Tags: php, xml

Me encuentro en la situación de tener que obtener el valor del atributo "version" de la declaración del fichero XML, tal que así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <TED_EXPORT DOC_ID="000002-2019">
  <TECHNICAL_SECTION>
    <RECEPTION_ID>18-587627-001</RECEPTION_ID>
    <DELETION_DATE>20190331</DELETION_DATE>
    <FORM_LG_LIST>DA DE EN ES FI FR EL IT NL PT SV CS ET HU LT LV MT PL SK SL GA BG RO HR </FORM_LG_LIST>
    <COMMENTS>From Convertor</COMMENTS>
  </TECHNICAL_SECTION>

  ....
```

Estoy probando con SimpleXML pero al cargar el fichero, lo que captura de inicio siempre es a partir de la primera etiqueta, por lo que no consigo acceder al campo de la versión.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/test.xml");

  /* DOC ID */
  $atributos = $xml->attributes();
  echo $atributos->DOC_ID;
```

Y este es el resultado que sale de print_r(xml)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [VERSION] => R2.0.9.S03.E01
            [DOC_ID] => 000001-2019
            [EDITION] => 2019001
        )

    [TECHNICAL_SECTION] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [RECEPTION_ID] => 18-583998-001
            [DELETION_DATE] => 20190207
            [FORM_LG_LIST] => DA DE EN ES FI FR EL IT NL PT SV CS ET HU LT LV MT PL SK SL GA BG RO HR 
            [COMMENTS] => From Convertor
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `SimpleXML` no te crea un objeto XML propiamente dicho. Revisando en la documentación no parece tener ninguna propiedad o método para acceder a la versión del documento mismo.

Puedes en cambio usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php), que sí trabaja con un objeto XML como tal y por tanto posee una propiedad [`xmlVersion`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.xmlversion) que guarda la versión del objeto al crearlo.

Por ejemplo:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xlm->load("xml/test.xml");
$xmlVersion = $xml->xmlVersion;
echo $xmlVersion;
```

No está de más decir que la lectura de cualquier otra parte del XML también es posible con `DOMDocument`.